# NetCore IPV6 socket connection fails on linux-arm

Tags: sockets, .net-core, ipv6

I am trying to establish an IPV6 socket connection with net-core 3.0 on a linux-arm platform (raspberry pi).

At the time when I try to bind the socket to the local ethernet adapter an Exception ((22): Invalid argument [fe80::211c:bf90:fbbf:9800]:5400) is thrown.

When i try the same on my windows development machine (with a different link-local ip), everything works fine.
IPV4 socket connection is also possible on both, my windows development machine and on the target linux-arm platform.

To the source code:
I used the socket example of microsoft as a base and changed the IPV4 into an IPV6 address.
The exception is thrown after the "Bind" method.

Here is the client side code:

```
  //definet the target endpoint
    IPAddress ipAddress;
    IPAddress.TryParse("fe80::211c:bf90:fbbf:9800", out ipAddress);
    IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 5400);

    // Create a TCP/IP  socket.  
    Socket sender = new Socket(ipAddress.AddressFamily ,SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

    //bind to the local network interface
    IPAddress localIp;
    IPAddress.TryParse("fe80::833:e68b:32ee:4c39", out localIp); 
    EndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.IPv6Any, 0);
    sender.Bind(localEndPoint);

    // Connect the socket to the remote endpoint. Catch any errors.  
    try
    {
      sender.Connect(remoteEP);

      Console.WriteLine("Socket connected to {0}",
          sender.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());
```

Comment: Where are you providing the Zone ID? Link-Local addresses need a Zone ID to determine the interface that should be used because all interfaces use the same Link-Local network.

Comment: hm, good point. basically this is my first ipv6 work, so i am not quite familiar with all the settings (as it seems).
so, do i have to pass the local zone id to the remote link local's address? and why is this different on windows an linux platforms? does windows have a more intelligent way to determine the NIC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The input of Ron was in fact the missing part. Hence the target endpoint IpAddress has to provided with the ScopeId (NIC Nr).

```
 //definet the target endpoint
    IPAddress ipAddress;
    IPAddress.TryParse("fe80::211c:bf90:fbbf:9800", out ipAddress);
    ipAddress.ScopeId = scopeId;
    IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 5400);
```

To the scope ID of the first link local address for example this code can be used:

```
private static long GetScopeIdForHostLinkLocal()
    {
      IPAddress firstLinkLocal = null;
      var info = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();

      foreach (NetworkInterface nic in info)
      {
        var ipProps = nic.GetIPProperties();
        var uniAddresses = ipProps.UnicastAddresses;
        foreach (UnicastIPAddressInformation addressInfo in uniAddresses)
        {
          if (addressInfo.Address.IsIPv6LinkLocal)
          {
            firstLinkLocal = addressInfo.Address;
            break;
          }
        }

        if (firstLinkLocal != null)
        {
          break;
        }
      }

      if (firstLinkLocal != null)
      {
        return firstLinkLocal.ScopeId;
      }
      else
      {
        return -1;
      }
    }
```